# Kubernetes manage traffic between pods replicas of several applications

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How to manage traffic between pods replicas of several applications?
I would like to get the effect for application A and B

> under A-x he always sent requests only to B-x and A-y only to B-y. And
>   that the platforms A-y and B-x do not communicate with each other.

Thank you in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using [Network policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

[This](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/network-policy/) is also a nice post about network policy.